# How do you get items from animals?

Tags: wild-arms-3

I am in the town of Jolly Roger and have used Jet's radar to scan for items. It highlights one of the cats as having an item. This also applies to various other animals found in different towns.

I have tried all the tools I have available and only two things have any response: Clive's bomb, and Gallows' freezer doll. However, neither results in an item.

How do I get the item from the animal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally worked out how to do it.

The tool you need is called the **Changecrest**. It is Virginia's 3rd and final tool, and it also happen to be the last of the 12 tools you obtain (3 per character).

The location of this tool is:

> Quite a while into the game (about 18 hours for me) you have to get access to a dungeon called "Cradle of the Metal God". This is accessed by a path called "Dim Root Path", in order to enter you must have all 12 guardians obtained. The Changecrest tool is the first treasure you find along the way.